Program and Program Enrollment Objects (Non-Profit Cloud) not visible on Salesforce Inspector
We're starting an implementation using Non-profit cloud and the Program and Program Enrollment Objects are not showing up in Salesforce Inspector. We've already done the steps below and this allowed us to see the records in the UI.

Enable Program and Benefit Management.

Add permission sets (Advance Program Management, Program and Benefit Management Access) and permission set licenses (Advance Program Management, Program and Benefit Management).

When we want to query Program and Program Enrollment objects or check the metadata using Salesforce Inspector. We can't see them.

The best resource for Nonprofit Cloud is this Trailblazer discussion group.  Have you posted there already?

Thank you! Just did!

It's due to Salesforce Inspector's API version (at least, testing on my end). Seems that Salesforce Inspector is still on API 56.0 and hasn't been updated in a while

I installed Salesforce Inspector Reloaded (which is up to date and lets you change API version) and can successfully see Program related entities once it's 57.0+ which is when it was introduced


Thank you! That explains it!
